# Javascript radio group by button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to display an alert msg when all radio button checked to `no`? I only know check radio by individual only.

```js
//I only know this method
$('#attraction1').change( function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert('Yes');
  }
});
```

```html
Attraction : 
  <input type="radio" id="attraction1" name="attraction" value="y" checked/> Yes
  <input type="radio" id="attraction2" name="attraction" value="n" /> No
<br>
Individual Attraction :
  <input type="radio" id="individual1" name="individual" value="y" checked/> Yes
  <input type="radio" id="individual2" name="individual" value="n" /> No
<br>
Plan Board: 
  <input type="radio" id="planBoard1" name="planBoard" value="y" checked/> Yes
  <input type="radio" id="planBoard2" name="planBoard" value="n" /> No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common class for all radio button with `no` value and a javascript array every method.

This line `const radioNames = [...document.getElementsByClassName('no')];` will get all the radio button with `no` value `...` is spread operator and will convert collection so that array method can be used on that collection.

This line `item.addEventListener('change', checkIfAllNo)` will attach event `change` to radio button with value `no` so that it checks the value for all other radio button

Array method `every` will return true if all the value in that array satisfies the condition.

So in this line `radioNames.every(item => {return item.checked;});` if all the radio button with `no` value is checked then `isAllFalse` will be true & the alert will be triggered.

```js
const radioNames = [...document.getElementsByClassName('no')];

function checkIfAllNo() {
  const isAllFalse = radioNames.every(item => {
    return item.checked;
  });
  if (isAllFalse) {
    alert('All False')
  }
}
radioNames.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('change', checkIfAllNo)
})
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="attraction1" name="attraction" value="y" checked/> Yes
<input type="radio" class="no" id="attraction2" name="attraction" value="n" /> No
<br> Individual Attraction :
<input type="radio" id="individual1" name="individual" value="y" checked/> Yes
<input type="radio" id="individual2" class="no" name="individual" value="n" /> No
<br> Plan Board:
<input type="radio" id="planBoard1" name="planBoard" value="y" checked/> Yes
<input type="radio" id="planBoard2" class="no" name="planBoard" value="n" /> No
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should check something like this

```
$('#some_button').click( function(){
  if ($('input[type="radio"][value="n"]:checked').length == 3) {
    alert('Yes');
  }
});
```

Comment: what if have more yes and no checkbox's, which I dont want to include in the condition? because currently it used `length`

Comment: than you should place class attribute to all radio you want to check - something like `class="need_to_check"` and than modify code like this
`if ($('.need_to_check:checked').length == 3) {
    alert('Yes');
  }`

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an indeterminate number of inputs you can collect the values for every group and then check if all values match

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
  // Extract all the radio group names
  names = $.unique($('input[type="radio"]').map((v, e) => $(e).attr('name')))
  
  // Collect the value for each group.
  // Account for groups that are not selected yet
  vals = $.map(names, function(name) {
    return $(`input:radio[name="${name}"]:checked`).val() || 'undefined';
  })
  // Check if collected values match 'n'
  console.log(vals.every(v => v == 'n'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Attraction :
<input type="radio" id="attraction1" name="attraction" value="y" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="attraction2" name="attraction" value="n" /> No
<br> Individual Attraction :
<input type="radio" id="individual1" name="individual" value="y" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="individual2" name="individual" value="n" checked/> No
<br> Plan Board:
<input type="radio" id="planBoard1" name="planBoard" value="y" checked/> Yes
<input type="radio" id="planBoard2" name="planBoard" value="n" /> No
```

Answer (score 0):

@ForeverTwoWheels

Please try this code,To Javascript radio group by button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Radio Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="yes"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="no"> No
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Show Selected Value">
    </form>
    <script>
        const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
        // handle click button
        btn.onclick = function () {
            const rbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choice"]');
            let selectedValue;
            for (const rb of rbs) {
                if (rb.checked) {
                    selectedValue = rb.value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            alert(selectedValue);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this information will be usefull for you.
Thank you.